# iOS NSPredicate on a deep to many relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I'm trying to check if a string contains my search strings (let's say "cr" for the example).

I have an object **A** which has multiple objects **B**, **B** has an `NSArray` (named array) of `NSDictionary`.

The `NSDictionary` has 2 keys : **@"desc"** and **@"action"**.

I would like to get all the objects of "A" where at least one of the desc key contains my searchString "cr".

I tried with:

```
NSPredicate *searchStringPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(SUBQUERY(A.B, $b, ANY $b.array.desc CONTAINS[cd] %@).@count > 0)", @"cr"];
```

But I keep getting a **EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x0) on :**

```
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

Do you have any idea of what's happening ?

Comment: Are you using Core Data or not?

Comment: I think you are fetching object from core data using predicate but am not clear about your object A and object B relationships. Can you clear little bit more?

Comment: Yes I am., the crash is happening on the executeFetchRequest

Comment: A has a one to many relationship with B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `A` has a relationship to `B` and `B` has a `transformable` `NSArray` (named `array`) of dictionaries as a property then you can not execute a fetch request to interrogate the contents of the `array`.

The `transformable` data is stored as binary in the data store so you can't access it until it has been read into memory and decoded.

If you need to be able to use a fetch request then you will need to convert the array of dictionaries into a relationship to another entity (and once you have done that the syntax of the subquery looks wrong).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried but I get an error : _'Can't have a non-relationship collection element in a subquery_. my root object is **A**, he has a **one to many relationship** with **B** who possess the array, do I need to make an other subquery to run through my NSSet of B objects ?

Comment: Yeah, I misunderstood the question initially - answer updated

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I know understand the problem, I need to create an entity for my NSDictionnary. I didn't know that it was stored as a binary. :)